# Fusing execution flow and exception flow in Scala

Tags: scala

I am using the following to wrap a Boolean function and return its success status:

```
  def wrapper(wrapped: => Boolean) : Boolean = { // this form of prototype takes a function by name
    try {
      return wrapped 
    } catch { 
        case anyException : Throwable => 
        log(anyException.toString)
        return false }
  }
```

The rationale being that the `wrapper` function should return an overall binary status, regardless of whether the `wrapped` function failed to capture its own unexpected exceptions and do the same. So the `wrapper` conveys success and failure via its Boolean return value. It can also be an `Option` for function result data, rather than a Boolean.

How would you accomplish this in other, even better ways, in Scala?

I note that one rationale (of few others) for this code, admittedly has been that try catch blocks are cumbersome in flow control blocks. Another has been that I tend to use this pattern a lot in a certain area of my project.

Comment: Isn't this a bit dangerous? Do you really want to catch out of memory errors? At the very least only catch exceptions and not throwables

Comment: Have you seen the [util.control.Exception](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.Exception$) object? It has lots of useful tools for making exception flow nicer.

Comment: Looks like you're on your way to re-inventing Try (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.Try)

Comment: I second Mikesname's suggestion that you look at scala.util.control.Exception. It can really help clean up code with lots of exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful! I wonder why Java-like try & catch blocks are still filling every tutorial out there... also good to know [a witch catcher](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.Exception%24) is at hand.. you know.. just in case ;) cute

Answer (score 2):

You can use Try. Although it will catch only NonFata(`scala.util.control.NonFatal`) but in most cases this is what you do want.

```
import scala.util.Try
def wrapper(predicate: => Boolean) : Boolean = {
  Try(predicate) getOrElse false
}
```

Or another way (For example if you really do want to catch any Throwable)

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._
def wrapper(predicate: => Boolean) : Boolean = {
  catching(classOf[Throwable]) opt predicate getOrElse false
}
```

Comment: hmmm, I looked at the source code of them, and couldn't become sure how can the exceptions also be logged while they are being swallowed in all these fancy ways... I would like control flow to proceed, but logs to contain exception details. did I miss anything about using `Try` and `control.Exception` in that regard?

Comment: Look at recover/recoverWith. They're like map/flatMap but for failures.

Comment: def wrapper(predicate: => Boolean) : Boolean = {
  (Try(predicate) recover {
    case _ =>
    // do logging here
    false
  }).get
}

Answer (score 1):

Scala provides Try feature, which is intended to be used in this occasions.

Notice that keeping your current wrapper leads to potential several errors. When you get a *false* result, you cannot know if it came from an application exception or a simple false evaluation. Thus, you can't properly handle any exception in your system, which may lead to multiple inconsistencies. Moreover, when you get a *false* result, your application internal state could be considered as unknown, making it very difficut to look into the box to know if the cat is dead or alive.

To solve this, scala's Try feature will handle this possible states for you, returning *-in your case-* a Success(elem: Boolean) in case your predicate effectively executes, and a Failure(ex: Throwable) in case an exception was thrown during execution. Then, you can use pattern matching to find out which was the case:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
[...]
Try(predicate) match {
  case Success(bool) => bool
  case Failure(ex) => /* Do something to handle ex */
}
```

This somehow eliminates the need of your wrapper, for you can keep Try's result and then either match it or get it's result whenever you need to. And, as seen in previous answers, there is a rather complete set of operations you can use to handle all this cases in a more fashionable way.

Comment: Thanks for the kind comments (and kind example of `Try`). In my case a failure is just failure, so the logic is not concerned with the cause of the exception or whether there had been an exception or just failure of my code to produce a result. I appreciate this is a different school of thought. The status will be the same for the caller. watching system health will be performed by logging all the exceptions and monitoring them outside the operational flow logic.... so the wave function well collapses.....